# How to preserve existing database connection?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm the developer of a PHP comments script which is designed to be included into the body of the users' websites. The script has its own database connection and currently uses the 'MySQL' extension. To make the script easier to integrate, I preserve the website's existing database connection (if there is one) by adding these two lines **before** connecting to the script's own connection ..

```
@$original_database = mysql_query('SELECT DATABASE();');
@$original_database = mysql_result($original_database, 0);
```

.. then **after** my script has finished I select the original database ..

```
if (!empty($original_database)) {
    @mysql_select_db ($original_database);
}
```

This is working fine at the moment. However many websites are (quite rightly) starting to use the newer extensions such as 'MySQLi' and 'PDO', and this makes it harder to preserve the existing database connection because for instance 'MySQLi' will complain that the connection is through 'MySQL'. Can you recommend the best way to deal with this? If it makes any difference, I plan to switch from 'MySQL' to 'MySQLi' in the near future, but obviously I will still have the same problem.

Comment: You should not be suppressing these functions at all.. You should tackle whatever error is being thrown

Comment: Have you profiled that code? Does it actually make a difference to do it like that? Also, by "preserve existing database connection," do you mean a *persistent connection*?

Comment: Sverri, by "preserve existing database connection", I mean that a user may integrate my script into a website like 'WordPress' for example. When my script has finished, I don't want the user to have to re-connect their 'WordPress' connection. I want my script to handle that for them.

Comment: It does not answer your actual question but I think it would be worth mentionning that doing that you're not preserving the connection at all. All you're doing is reconnect the same database as you were previously connected to. Through php as a module of apache you can't preserve connections between each script. Even with persistent connections you're not sure of how the pool is dealt with, this is totally internal to mysql, and that engine only decides what to do with the connections since *each time a php script is finished, it dies*.

Comment: Sebas, you're right, "reconnect to original database" would have been a more accurate title.

Comment: Okay so I've done some testing and I've found that I only need to reconnect the original database if my script is using the **same** extension as the user's website. For example, if my script uses the 'MySQL' extension, (which it currently is), then I don't need to reconnect if the website is using 'MySQLi' or 'PDO'. The code from my original question is actually perfect because the variable $original_database is null when the website uses 'MySQLi' and 'PDO', so it won't attempt to reconnect at the end. I would add this as an answer except Stack Overflow wants me to wait 8 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Always use **'MySQLi'**

```
function custom_mysqli_connect(){
    $GLOBALS['db_connect']=false;
    $GLOBALS['db_connect']=@mysqli_connect(HOSTNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    if($GLOBALS['db_connect']==false){
        echo("Unable to connect to the database");
    }
    if(!@mysqli_select_db($GLOBALS['db_connect'], DATABASE)){
        echo("Unable to select database");
    }
    mysqli_query($GLOBALS['db_connect'],'SET NAMES UTF8');
}
```

Call **custom_mysqli_connect()** once

Make your queries:

```
$query_1 = "SELECT * FROM table";

if($results=@mysqli_query($GLOBALS['db_connect'], $query_1)){

   $array=array();

   while($result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){

      $array[]=$result;

   }    

   mysqli_free_result($results);

}
```

When your are done

```
@mysqli_close($GLOBALS['db_connect']);
```

There is plenty of other ways to fetch the results

> mysqli_ result:: fetch_ all
>
> mysqli_ result:: fetch_ array
>
> mysqli_ result:: fetch_ assoc
>
> mysqli_ result:: fetch_ field_ direct
>
> mysqli_ result:: fetch_ field
>
> mysqli_ result:: fetch_ fields
>
> mysqli_ result:: fetch_ object
>
> mysqli_ result:: fetch_ row

See: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.summary.php

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure how this is exactly relevant to the question. This just seems to be an explanation of how to use 'MySQLi'.

Comment: As long as you don't close your connection with @mysqli_close($GLOBALS['db_connect']); your existing database connection is preserved.